# Bash - get notification from nmap output if out of IP range

Tags: bash, nmap

I'm trying to create a script to give me a notification of specific conditions of an nmap scan on my network. If I use this command in the script:

```
nmap -n -sP 192.168.15.0/24 | awk '/^Nmap scan/{IP=$5};/^MAC/{print IP,$3};{next}'
```

How can I make the script tell me if the IP range is past 192.168.15.124?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific.
In my script, I plan on using my nmap scan. What I want to know is if it is possible that whatever the output if I would be able to put in an if/then/else statement to echo something if the output is in a certain range. Like so:

if range=192.168.15.1-124 then echo "Output is within normal parameters" elif range>192.168.15.124 then echo "Warning!! Too many IP addresses"

Or something like that. Does bash have the intelligence to interpret IP address ranges? Or, would something like this require a language more advanced like Python or Perl?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that nmap's output is:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.15.117
MAC : 00:11:22:33:44:55
Nmap scan report for 192.168.15.125
MAC : 0a:1b:2c:3d:4e:5f
```

To print out `Beyond` whenever the IP range is 124 or beyond:

```
$ nmap -n -sP 192.168.15.0/24 | awk '/^Nmap scan/{IP=$5; n=split($5, a, /[.]/); f=(a[n]>=124?"Beyond":"")};/^MAC/{print IP,$3,f};{next}'
192.168.15.117 00:11:22:33:44:55 
192.168.15.125 0a:1b:2c:3d:4e:5f Beyond
```

#### How it works

There are two steps.  The first splits the IP address on periods:

```
n=split($5, a, /[.]/)
```

The second step sets variable `f` according to whether the last octet of the IP address was 124 or greater:

```
f=(a[n]>=124 ? "Beyond" : "")
```